# How to retrieve a subset of fields using the C# MongoDB driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've searched the world over and can't seem to find the answer to this.

How do I do this in C#:

```
// retrieve ssn field for documents where last_name == 'Smith':
db.users.find({last_name: 'Smith'}, {'ssn': 1});
```

Thanks!

Comment: OK, well, I was misreading an example elsewhere, but just for the record, here is the solution:

    users.FindAs<User>(Query.EQ("_id", "test@foo.com"))
        .SetFields(Fields.Include(new string[] { "first_name", "last_name" }))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb -- include or exclude certain elements with c# driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448179/mongodb-include-or-exclude-certain-elements-with-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: Hm. Kind of the other way around, really. This thread is older, but they are dups of each other.

Comment: The other question has a better answer though, and that's what should count. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/885318

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you can now use a **(type/refactoring)-safe** version:

```
usersCollection.FindAllAs<User>()
               .SetFields(Fields<User>.Include(user => user.FirstName,
                                               user => user.LastName)
                                      .Exclude(user => user.SSN)
               .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 16):

To include:

```
.SetFields(Fields.Include("first_name", "last_name"));
```

To exclude fields:

```
.SetFields(Fields.Exclude("SSN","Salary"));
```

To do both:

```
.SetFields(Fields.Include("first_name", "last_name").Exclude("SSN","Salary"));
```