# Is foreach with FindAsync is good for performance?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a fairly short, but it seems to me, questionable query in terms of performance:

```
        List<Example> examples = await _dataContext.Examples.ToListAsync();

        foreach (Example example in examples)
        {
            User? user = await _dataContext.Users.FindAsync(example.UserId);

            if (user != null) user.Points += example.Worth * example.Multiplier;
        }

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await _dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("TRUNCATE TABLE\"Examples\"");
```

Is this option really bad for performance and are there any alternatives to it? Thank you!

Comment: Before thinking in performance, you should think about the logic. This code will update all `user.Points` every time it's called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Find and FindAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650722/difference-between-find-and-findasync)

Comment: @PoulBak Of course, I understand this, but note that the data from the example (Worth, Multiplier) can be different, which is why, based on my knowledge (which, of course, is not complete), a one-time request cannot be generated

Comment: If your `Example` entity contains reference navigation property to `User` (e.g. `public User User { get; set; }`) as it should, then simply use [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager), e.g. `_dataContext.Examples.Include(e => e.User)...` and then inside the loop simply use `example.User` property instead of `Find{Async}`. Performance will be better due to single vs N+1 database queries for retrieving the data.

Answer (score 2):

To use contains to fetch multiple entities is much faster.
If the entity list to load is large, it is best to split the contains to a fix size. This will ensure to hit the SQL-query cache on the server.

Your example makes a bit no sense. The points should be updated on "example" creation and the fastest possible in your example would be to write a UPDATE RAW-SQL to calc. and update the points server site.

Here is the better batch lookup method (assuming example-ids are coming from somewhere else then the database)

```cs
 List<Example> examples = await _dataContext.Examples.ToListAsync();

 var exampleIds = examples.Select(n => n.UserId).Chunk(10);

        foreach (var ids in exampleIds)
        {
            var userQuery = _dataContext.Users.Where(n => ids.Contains(n.UserId));

           await foreach(var user in userQuery.AsAsyncEnumerable())
           {
              user.Points += example.Worth * example.Multiplier;
           }
        }

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await _dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("TRUNCATE TABLE\"Examples\"");
```

Comment: As I understand it, I messed up the architecture very much, thanks for the right direction!