# C# Mongodb - Get only the specified fields of documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a `User.cs` model as follows:

```
uid: string
name: string
email: string
password: string
friends: List<string>
```

I get all users from a mongodb collection using the following code:

```
List<User> users = null;
var query = await _userCollection.FindAsync<User>(user => true);
users = await query.ToListAsync();
```

The elements in the `users` list have the same fields as the `User` model.

Now I want the returned elements or documents to have every field except `password`. I searched online and found that we can use `SetFields` but I am not able to found any code or links to follow. If possible, I would like to keep the method `async`.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: FYI: You should not be storing plain-text passwords. Please make sure you understand proper security if this is something with real users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need just to exclude the password field from the result, you need to use Projection: https://digitteck.com/mongo-csharp/projections_in_mongo_csharp/. Also the second answer here: [Mongodb -- include or exclude certain elements with c# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448179/mongodb-include-or-exclude-certain-elements-with-c-sharp-driver) (the first one is about legacy driver)