# MongoDB C# Query Select specific keys from document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can i do this from c# mongoDb drivers.

sql query  :`SELECT a,b FROM users`

mondb javascript query : `db.users.find({}, {a:1,b:1})`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a subset of fields using the C# MongoDB driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540160/how-to-retrieve-a-subset-of-fields-using-the-c-sharp-mongodb-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
 var database = MongoDatabase.Create(connectionString);
 var userCollection = database.GetCollection<Exercise>("users");
 var users = userCollection.Find().SetFields("a", "b");
```

If I understand your question correctly .SetFields does what you want.